# Why are column and row used differently in HTML than in dictionary?

Tags: html

As I understand it, column is vertical and row is horizontal.
But if I write the syntax to implement it in HTML, it will be implemented in the opposite way.
If I implement the code written below, it looks like cols means horizontal. Why?

```html
<h3>3. Textarea</h>
<label for="request">Sonderwünsche</label>
<textarea name="Frage" id="request" cols="50" rows="5" placeholder="Schreiben Sie hier!">
</textarea>
```

[image]

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because this question is about the English language and not about programming per se.

Comment: This is a perfectly normal use of the terms "row" and "column". It works the same way in bus timetables, knitting, bingo, spreadsheets, and everything else. https://ell.stackexchange.com/ would probably be a better place to ask this question.

Answer (score 0):

It creates 5 horizontal rows and divides that horizontal rows into 30 vertical columns. Please find below image for the reference.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/cMpY5.png

Comment: Thanks for the reply! It's really easy to understand with picture attached. Unfortunately I just signed up today so I can't vote for your opinion. But thank you so much!

Comment: you may please accept my answer as the best answer